# Как открыть модальное окно один раз?

Tags: php, jquery, cookie

помогите понять почему модальное окно с выбором города открывается при каждой перезагрузке?

```js
var part = document.location.href;
    if (part == 'https://site.ru/') {
        
        function getCookie(name) {
            var value = "; " + document.cookie;
            var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
            if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
        }

        if (!getCookie("region")) {
            $.fancybox.open({
                src: "#region-modal",
                type: "inline",
                opts: {
                    afterShow: function () {
                        
                        $("#region-form").submit(function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            
                            document.cookie = "region=" + $("#region-select").val() + "; path=/";
                            
                            window.location.href = "https://" + $("#region-select").val() + ".site.ru";
                        });
                    },
                    afterClose: function () {
                        
                        if (!getCookie('region')) {
                            
                            setCookie('region', 'true');
                        }
                    }
                },
            });
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="region-modal" class="region-modal" style="display: none;">
  <h2>Выберите город отправления</h2>
 
    <form id="region-form" class="region-form">
    <select name="region" id="region-select" class="region-select"><?php
      foreach( $regions as $city ){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $city['value'] ?>"><?php echo $city['name'] ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="button region-btn">Выбрать</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Скорее всего getCookie ничего не возвращает (`parts.length == 2` не равно), а значит `if (!getCookie("region")) {` всегда true, соответственно, всегда открывается модалка.